# Kafka KO (Broker may not be available) : number of connection attempts

Tags: apache-kafka

In my application I have to handle the case where Kafka is not available. In this case (which I voluntarily provide by stopping the Kafka server), my client makes repeated attempts to connect for 6 minutes. How can I change these 6 minutes of attempts? Is there a property to change the 6 minute wait?
Thank you

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the client timeout configurations? Which ones have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies.

So, with Kafka down, the call that is on hold for 6 minutes is this (I use it to then ask for Kafka's status):

```
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = streamsBuilder.getKafkaStreams (); // 6 minute wait (WARN Broker may not be available)
state = kafkaStreams.state ();
```

or, I tried alternatively, but nothing changes, this call:

```
streamsBuilder.isRunning (); // 6 minute wait (WARN Broker may not be available)
```

Variables I have set:

```
spring.kafka.streams.auto-startup = false
spring.kafka.producer.acks = all
spring.kafka.producer.retries = 600
spring.kafka.producer.properties.retry.backoff.ms = 100
spring.kafka.producer.properties.linger.ms = 0
```

I also tried using KafkaAdmin (FastFail) to no avail:

```
kafkaAdmin.setFatalIfBrokerNotAvailable(true);
/ * speed up fail fast * /
kafkaAdmin.setOperationTimeout(5);
kafkaAdmin.setCloseTimeout(5);
```

Thank you